# Does Grails have any plugins similar to the django-debug-toolbar (djdt)?

Tags: grails

Does Grails have any plugins with functionality similar to the django-debug-toolbar (djdt)?

See [this screencast for an introduction to djdt](http://robhudson.github.com/django-debug-toolbar/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why yes it does [grails debug-toolbar](http://www.grails.org/plugin/debug-toolbar):

> Grails Debug Toolbar is a plugin
> inspired from Django Debug Toolbar

While it doesn't have all the features of djdt it is planned to expand the feature set in the future, here is relevant section from their webpage:

> **Future work**
>
> - Currently the views of debugtoolbar
>   need to go in the grails-app/views of
>   the application. When you install the
>   plugin they are automatically copied
>   to your application grails-app/views.
>   Need to avoid this.
> - JavaScript and
>   static resources for the toolbar
>   reside in web-app/debugtoolbar. It is
>   also copied to your application
>   web-app/debugtoolbar. Need to avoid
>   this.
> - A way of ordering the panels in
>   the toolbar. Currently it is random
>   depending on how beans are found
>   during execution of tag.
> - More useful panels such as Timing the requests, SQL queries, logging etc

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about that one. It seems like a step in the right direction, but unfortunately it lacks some of the more useful djdt panels such as request timing and SQL query details. Do you know of any other options?

Comment: Unfortunately this was the only equivalent I could find, but the missing features are planned for in the future, I've updated my answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

It not quite a toolbar (and not a plugin) but Spring Insight gives you detailled request timing right down to the JDBC level. It integrates pretty nicely with Spring Tool Suite from what I've seen.

Check out Peter's screencast: http://www.grails.org/blog/view/pledbrook/New+screencast%3A+Profiling+with+STS+%26+Spring+Insight

You need to deploy your app to Spring's tcServer rather than a plain tomcat which might be fine for development tuning.

cheers

Lee